# JNI Global reference to PacketWriter in smack library, how to identify the cause JNI Global referece?

Tags: java, debugging, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

I am using smack library to connect to Facebook XMPP server.

In my local enviroment debug mode, memory leak sometimes happened. I have:

- checked the heap dump,
- found that JNI Global reference always referred to PacketWriter object in smack library,
- PacketWriter contains one thread to do output work

**Question:** 
what caused the JNI Global reference? (of course no JNI used in the server)

Is the JNI Glabal reference caused by debug mode of the server?

I already checked the question: [How to identify the cause of a JNI global reference memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423873/how-to-identify-the-cause-of-a-jni-global-reference-memory-leak).

[This](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/browse/smack/trunk) is smack source code view:

**Update**
the heap dump is very big, I post the screenshot of VisualVM about heap
http://sphotos-a.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/21927_384581804957834_1241962037_n.jpg

Comment: Can you post the heap dump somewhere?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify the cause of a JNI global reference memory leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6423873/how-to-identify-the-cause-of-a-jni-global-reference-memory-leak)